# mp3 to wav with ffmpeg reduces quality and duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I took [this mp3 file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/axrgs4qhuves9wg/Casey%20Don%E2%80%99t%20You%20Fret%20-%20Dan%20Lebowitz.mp3) and converted it to wav with Audition and with this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i "Casey Don’t You Fret - Dan Lebowitz.mp3" -c:a pcm_f32le "Casey Don’t You Fret - Dan Lebowitz_FFMPEG.wav"
```

After that I checked the statistics in Audition. The wav file which was generated with Audition has exactly the same statistics as the original mp3 file.

[image]

The duration of ffmpeg file has changed. Audio statistics became worse.
Why is this happening? Can I fix it?

I used `ffmpeg version 2020-11-22-git-0066bf4d1a-full_build-www.gyan.dev` on Windows.

**UPDATE 1:**
I cut a few seconds of mp3 at the beginning and at the end:

[image]

FFMPEG added silence at the beginning and increased duration.

**UPDATE 2:**
Look how ffmpeg changed the waveform of [this `2.mp3` file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/3mjjs8amwydllug/2.mp3) in the middle:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 2.mp3 -c:a pcm_f32le 2_FFMPEG.wav
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Audacity doesn't skip the priming samples so its decoded output has the silent samples at front and back. That will increase the min. RMS and thus range. Compare the same middle portion in both WAVs.

Comment: I did what you said. FFMPEG adds silence at the beginning. And changes the waveform in the middle. I think I found a bug. I updated the post.

Comment: That waveform difference looks like an edge case for the decoder - either ffmpeg or Audition's.

Comment: How did you generate the cut MP3?

Comment: I opened `Casey... .mp3` in `Audition`, manually cut a few seconds from head and tail and exported to `Casey... _CUT.mp3`. Then sent this file to `ffmpeg` and got `Casey... _FFMPEG.wav`. What do you mean by edge case for the decoder? `mpg123` and `Audition` do `mp3` to `wav` without any change in the middle of the waveform.

Comment: Need to decode with a reference decoder to identify which decoders show anomaly.

Comment: And how to implement it?